# @PartType cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I don't know what library I should include to be able to use `@PartType("application/json")` annotation when outputing `multipart/mixed` data with resteasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using maven, add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using maven, add the resteasy-multipart-provider-2.2.1.GA.jar to your classpath.